# Jquery works but only for a moment

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a row's select button is clicked, a confirmation box pops up.

Upon confirming the box, the select-button shall become disabled, and a message is appended that shall fade out.

Both, button disabling and message appending work but only for a second. 
The button does not remain disabled. Also the message appends correctly but only for a second too.

I could change the fadeOut(Int) to any Integer but still the message only shows up for a second. Why does functionality only work for a second?

```
<script>
    $('#button_<?php echo $platform->id; ?>').click(function() {
        var choice = confirm('Please confirm that you wish to do the following Platform: <?php echo $platform->company; ?>');
        if (choice == true) {
            $('#button_<?php echo $platform->id; ?>').prop("disabled", true);
            $('.job_confirm').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('.job_confirm').append('The Job has been added to your Userarea -->');
            $('.job_confirm').fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like your button is a submit button that reloads the page

Comment: @MarmiK If this code is generated from PHP, those substitutions are fine.

Comment: in this case Kanishka's answer below should do :)

Comment: Vicky: It already worked, so the script is obviously after the button has rendered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `event.preventDefault();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#button_<?php echo $platform->id; ?>').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var choice = confirm('Please confirm that you wish to do the following Platform: <?php echo $platform->company; ?>');
        if (choice == true) {
            $('#button_<?php echo $platform->id; ?>').prop("disabled", true);
            $('.job_confirm').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('.job_confirm').append('The Job has been added to your Userarea -->');
            $('.job_confirm').fadeOut(5000);
        }
        });

</script>
```